# Why am I getting an error message in my dashboard for unprotected private files?

Tags: 8, installation, security

I have a site with Drupal 8.9

Why am I getting an error message in my dashboard for unprotected private files ?

When I go to the link it says this is for Drupal 6 and 7.

```
PRIVATE FILES DIRECTORY
Not fully protected
See https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 for information about the recommended .htaccess file which should be added to the private:// directory to help protect against arbitrary code execution.
```

https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2013-11-20/sa-core-2013-003-drupal-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, which is reported by [`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/8.9.x), means that either that directory doesn't contain any .htaccess file, or that .htaccess file doesn't contain the following lines.

```
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>
```

Together the lines added from a previous security advisory, they avoid files in that directory can be executed.

```
# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>
```

Before showing that error message, Drupal tries to create the .htaccess file. (See [`HtaccessWriter::write()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21HtaccessWriter.php/function/HtaccessWriter%3A%3Awrite/8.9.x).) If it's not able to create it, or write into that file, you should manually create the .htaccess file containing the following lines.

```
# Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

The same lines are shown in the error message contained in the Drupal log.

Comment: My server is an Nginx server. What is the use of this file ?

Comment: In addition, the Private directory is outside the Drupal root. The documentation dates from 2023 and does not at any time mention Drupal 8. So I do not understand.

Comment: The private directory is still a directory where Drupal could write files uploaded from users, and it needs to be protected from malicious scripts users could put there. The code I linked is used from Drupal 8, so that is still relevant for Drupal 8. I would find it strange, if Drupal 8 didn't protect against script execution in directory potentially containing file uploaded from users.

Comment: .htaccess files are for Apache HTTP server or for its drop-down replacements. For Nginx, [How can I use an .htaccess file in Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766676/how-can-i-use-htaccess-file-in-nginx) can help in porting a .htaccess file to Nginx configuration.